# What does it mean in php to use strstr as a boolean check?

Tags: php, boolean, strstr

For example given code:

```
if(strstr($key, ".")){
    // do something
}
```

strstr returns a string, how can it be used as boolean? How does it turn true or false?

Comment: `Returns the portion of string, or FALSE if needle is not found.` So, if the result is not FALSE, it means it's TRUE (as in truish, though, not as in boolean.) Basically is a check for a NON-FALSE value

Comment: So returns if there is no "." in this situation? Interesting.. Is this documented? Because I thought this method returned a string not a boolean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citing from [the PHP docu](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php):

> Returns the portion of string, or FALSE if needle is not found.

So the boolean check is basically, whether the substring (the `.` in this case) is found at all.

Any other value this function can return is a non-empty string, which will be evaluated to truthy (See [this entry](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) in docu.)

Comment: Thanks. But if it returns the portion of the string, how is this true?

Comment: @KorayTugay Edited. Basically everything, that is not false, 0 or empty is evaluated to true in an `if`-clause.

Answer (score 2):

here is an example

```
 <?php
 $email  = 'name@example.com';
 $domain = strstr($email, '@');
 echo $domain; // prints @example.com

 $user = strstr($email, '@', true); // As of PHP 5.3.0
 echo $user; // prints name
 ?>
```

**definition:**

The `strstr()` function searches for the first occurrence of a string inside another string.
This function returns the rest of the string (from the matching point), or FALSE, if the string to search for is not found.

```
    strstr(string,search)
```

`string` ---->    Required. Specifies the string to search

`search` ---->    Required. Specifies the string to search for. If this parameter is a number, it will search for the character matching the ASCII value of the number.

Comment: Doesn't seem to answer the question I don't see anything referring to the 'Boolean' part ?

Answer (score 1):

This is simple: in an if statement , when we have a value that is empty for example a non empty string , this is true. For example:

```
if("test") { //this is true
}

$value = "test";
if($value) { //this is true
}


$value = 3;
if($value) { //this is true
}
```

On the other hand when you have an empty variable then in if statement it acts like false. For example:

```
$var = 0;
if($var) { //this is false
}

$var = false;
if($var) { //this is false
}

$var = "";
if($var) { //this is false
}
```

So in your case you have:

```
$key = "test.com"
$val = strstr($key, "."); //Return ".com" 

if ($val) { //This is not a non empty string so it is true
}

$key = "justtest"
$val = strstr($key, "."); //Return boolean false so it is false

if ($val) { //This is returning boolean false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The return of strstr is either boolean (false) or string, then

```
$strstr = strstr($key, '.');
if(is_string($strstr)){
 echo 'is found';
}

or 

if($strstr === false){
 echo 'not found';
}
```

Note: is_bool($strtsr) also can be used because the string will not be casted to bool (true)

```
echo is_bool('test') ? 'true' : 'false'; //false
```